# Trying to remember a movie with a fairy burning butterfly collection

Tags: story-identification, movie

I probably saw the movie on TV or VHS in Norway sometime between 1992 and 1998. The style was a lot like *The Indian in the Cupboard* and *The Borrowers*. Most likely a children's or teen movie.

I think this movie was about a child (I think it was a boy) that had befriended a female fairy. The only thing I can remember  was a scene with the fairy crying inside a room because she had found a butterfly collection that either belonged to the child or someone in the family. I think the fairy used telekinetic like magic to send the butterfly collection into a fireplace or a stove and then set them on fire because she felt betrayed by the child and mourned the death of all the butterflies.

I think the child was locked outside the door trying to explain why the butterflies was killed and framed and desperately begged the fairy for forgiveness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found your movie. It's "[Motýlí cas O Mundo Mágico de Alec](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0100194/)" (known as "The Flying Sneaker" in English)

> Little Rehor isn't allowed to play with the other boys. His only friend is the girl next door, Luci. Rehor's father is doctor on a boat and he has sent Rehor a package with butterfly larvae. When they hatch he discover a fairy who can do magic tricks.

You can watch the full movie online here (timeshifted to the scene with the burning butterflies)

Comment: Don't worry about your English, that can be fixed. But please can you add *why* you think this is the correct answer: how does this video match the points in the question?

Comment: @Wikis - I've found the scene in question. It seems a pretty solid match

Comment: It's been broadcast in scandinavia on channel svtB according to http://www.tvinfo.se/program2181809.html. It also has two different swedish titles according to http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0100194/releaseinfo?ref_=tt_dt_dt#akas

Comment: Congratulations on getting your first ever answer accepted; quite an achievement!

Comment: @Wikis I too watched my old movies. How match? I artist and drawed butterfly arts collection :) You can try find helping for website [link](http:///www.whatismymovie.com)